# MS Graph subscription - $expand

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've set up a microsoft graph subscription for calendar Events, with included resource data. It's working perfectly with a simple $select.

Now I'm trying to add an $expand clause. Via trial and error, I discovered that only two properties are apparently available to be expanded in the included resource data:

```
Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: BadRequest; Reason: $top, $skip, $orderby, 
  $select=body,uniqueBody and 
  $expand other than singleValueExtendedProperties,multiValueExtendedProperties 
  are not supported in subscription resource Url.]
```

So now I'm trying to expand `singleValueExtendedProperties`. I've discovered that a $filter seems to be a reqirement when expanding, and I found a filter that works when using the `GET /me/event/{id}` endpoint:

```
$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq '{id_value}')"
```

(using [singleValueExtendedProperties docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) as reference)

However when I add this to the create subscription call, I get a strange error:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions

{
    "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
    "encryptionCertificate": "{base64-public-cert-data}",
    "encryptionCertificateId": "{cert-id}",
    "expirationDateTime": "{expire-time}",
    "includeResourceData": true,
    "lifecycleNotificationUrl": "https://my.site.com/Webhook",
    "notificationUrl": "https://my.site.com/Webhook",
    "resource": "me/events?$select=Subject,Start,End&$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties(%24filter=id eq '{id_value}')"
}
```

This results in the following error:

```
code:    ExtensionError
message: Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: BadRequest; 
   Reason: Could not find a property named 'PropertyId' 
   on type 'microsoft.graph.singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty'.]
```

This seems to be a bug: like on the back-end it's replacing `id` with `PropertyId`. I've tried dozens of permutations through the [graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer), including multiple url escapings (%20 etc), and trying to filter on value, and not filtering at all.

For some of these (e.g. no filter, `$filter=value eq '{value}'`), it will generate a subscription, but the expand data doesn't show up in the resource data after decrypting.

Has anyone found a way around this? The same thing happens when using  `multiValueExtendedProperties`.

Note: I initially tried using the `v1.0` API, but subscriptions for the `Event` type are only supported via the `beta` API.